# Airflow:OracleHook:bulk_insert_rows:Task exited with return code Negsignal.SIGKILL

Tags: python-3.x, airflow

I am loading data from S3 into Oracle by looping chunk size of 10000 rows but it's causing into memory issue after looping some rows:

Error: `Task exited with return code Negsignal.SIGKILL`

```
    def gen_chunks(self,reader, chunksize=10000):
        chunk = []
        for i, line in enumerate(reader):
            if (i % chunksize == 0 and i > 0):
                yield list(map(tuple, chunk))
                chunk = []
            chunk.append(line)
        yield list(map(tuple, chunk))

    def execute(self, context):
        self.s3_key = self.get_s3_key(self.s3_key)
        s3_hook = S3Hook()
        s3_client = s3_hook.get_conn()
        snflk_hook = SnowflakeHook(snowflake_conn_id=self.snowflake_conn_id)
        orcl = OracleHook(oracle_conn_id=self.oracle_conn_id)
        try:
            with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as f_source:
                s3_client.download_file(self.s3_bucket, self.s3_key, f_source.name)
                logger.info('Source file downloaded succesfully')
                with open(f_source.name, 'r') as f:
                    csv_reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='|')
                    for chunk in self.gen_chunks(csv_reader):
                        orcl.bulk_insert_rows(table=self.oracle_table,rows=chunk, target_fields=self.target_fields,  commit_every=10000)
        except Exception as ex:
            raise AirflowException(f'Error: {ex}')
```

Comment: Check https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/10435

Answer (score 0):

Fix it by reducing the `commit_every` parameter to `3000`.

```py
for chunk in self.gen_chunks(csv_reader):
    orcl.bulk_insert_rows(table=self.oracle_table,rows=chunk, target_fields=self.target_fields, commit_every=3000)
```

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/64185704/2) to the question [Airflow:OracleHook:bulk_insert_rows:Task exited with return code Negsignal.SIGKILL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64185704/airfloworaclehookbulk-insert-rowstask-exited-with-return-code-negsignal-sigki) by the OP [Kar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12955349/kar) under CC BY-SA 4.0.</sub>